# Is it possible to use AWS Glue Connection to create a data source?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm trying to access a database in the private subnet in the AWS Glue job script. As far as see in the documentation, one can create a data source using different "connection types" and appropriate "connection options", but they don't support VPC settings.

The only thing, which supports VPC settings is AWS Glue Connection, but I cannot find a way how to create a Spark data source using AWS Glue Connection.

Or maybe there is a some workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See step 8 in this [guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/connecting-to-and-running-etl-jobs-across-multiple-vpcs-using-a-dedicated-aws-glue-vpc/), after you add your Glue jdbc connection, create a crawler to import table metadata from the source database into the AWS Glue Data Catalog.

Then you can access the table within a Glue job like this:

```
df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "db1", table_name = "table1")
```

Or with Spark:

```
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM db1.table1")
```

Comment: But then I wouldn't have real time data. I can actually connect directly to Postgres from Spark, but there is no VPC settings. There're only in Connection configuration

Comment: Why not? the crawler does not pull the data from pg db, it pulls the metadata and creates a table reference in Glue catalog. When you run your Glue / Spark job it will query pg directly using jdbc. Means real time data.

Comment: Ok, I see. Somehow I thought that Catalog tables can be only S3 backed. Thank you!